# How to change the display name for in the view of a MVC5 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to change the Display Name of the fields in an MVC5 application.  I’ve annotated the Data Model with the desired name:

```
[DisplayName("State")]
public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }
```

However, when I go to the View (Razor) I can’t come up with a combination of LabelFor or other statements to display the updated value.  Should be simple, but it’s not.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StateOrProvinceName) – Fails
@Html.LabelNameFor(model => model.StateOrProvinceName) – Fails
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StateOrProvinceName) – Fails
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateOrProvinceName “State”) – Fails
```

Is there a syntaxial  reference or technique I’m omitting ?

Comment: Use `[Display(Name = "State")]` (and `DisplayFor()` displays the value of the property, and there is no such thing as `LabelNameFor()` in the framework).

Comment: I modified the Model with the [Display(Name = "State") decoration, but I still don't know how to display the updated value on the View page.  Utilizing DisplayNameFor, still utilizes the EF Field name from SQL

Comment: Not if your using the model which is decorated with that attribute. I can only assume your not using the correct model.

Comment: I didn't regenerate the model because this would have reset the attribute.  The view is pointing to the original model and I would assume this would automatically work.  How to I ensure that I am using the correct model?  I haven't changed any of the relationships, so I assumed it would all work.

Comment: Stephen, I verified I was using the right model by adding other annotations which restricted text input on the view form (Edit).  However, I discovered a typo which caused the problem.  Without changing the DisplayFor Pneumonic in the View page works as advertised.  Thanks for the help and for responding.